# Rails - Google Cloud Messaging server side with Rails

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am building a sample android app with notifications and live chatting, i am trying to use GCM so that the server (Ruby on Rails) can talk to the clients (Android).

For the Android part, I'm following this [tutorial](http://hmkcode.com/android-google-cloud-messaging-tutorial/), but for Rails, I found many gems like [rpush](https://github.com/rpush/rpush), [pushmeup](https://github.com/NicosKaralis/pushmeup) and more, but I am new to Rails so I couldn't figure were should I write the code and how to run it and test it.

Can someone walk me through it or give me a link to a detailed tutorial?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: flush seems better maintained, I would go with that one, instructions are in the link you pasted.

Comment: Check Rpush gem: https://github.com/rpush/rpush You can also check the following tutorial for a Rails-Android GCM sample application
http://mateuyabar.com/blog/android/rubyonrails/gcm/2015/05/13/Google-Cloud_Messaging-with-Ruby-On-Rails.html